# Adobe AIR - SQL statement against DB

Tags: sqlite, air, adobe

This is my javascript for Adobe Air:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setupDB();

    var tasks = getTasks();
    $("#tasks").empty();

    var numRecords = tasks.data.length;

    for(i=0; i<numRecords; i++) {
        $("<li/>").append('<span>'+ tasks.data[i].id +' - '+ tasks.data[i].task +'</span>').appendTo("#tasks");
    }
});


var db = new air.SQLConnection();

function setupDB() {

    var dbFile = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("airTasks.db");

    try {
        db.open(dbFile);    

    } catch (error) {
        alert("DB Error: "+ error.message);
        alert("Details: "+ error.details);

        air.trace("DB Error: "+ error.message);
        air.trace("Details: "+ error.details);  
    }
}

function getTasks() {   

    var query = new air.SQLStatement();
    query.sqlConnection = db;
    query.text = "SELECT id, task FROM tasks";

    try {
        query.execute();

    } catch(error) {
        alert("Error getting tasks from DB: "+ error.message +", DETAILS: "+ error.details);

        air.trace("Error getting tasks from DB: "+ error);
        air.trace(error.message);

        return; 
    }

    return query.getResults();
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Database Version 3 - airTasks.db
[image]

I keep getting:

> ERROR: Table "tasks" not found.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your filepath being opened actually exists. If it doesn't, SQLite creates one for you.

Try this to troubleshoot before you call `db.open()`:

```
alert(dbFile);
```

Is this the correct path to your db?

Comment: So it returned an [object]... and then yes the correct file-path, as it is in the root of the app.